# Storing the name of several folders in a variable list

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I have 47 folders (100, 00, 01, 02, ..., 43, 44, 45). I want to store the name of these folders inside a list so that I can build a pandas Dataframe with it. So far, I have this code:

```py
import os
import glob
path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/data/classes/'
ListOfClasses = []
for file in glob.glob (path + '/*'):
    ListOfClasses.append(file)
ListOfClasses
```

However, the names of the folders come out like this (They also come unorganized):

```
['/content/drive/MyDrive/data/classes/42',
 '/content/drive/MyDrive/data/classes/43',
 '/content/drive/MyDrive/data/classes/36',
 '/content/drive/MyDrive/data/classes/45',
 ...,
 '/content/drive/MyDrive/data/classes/00',
 '/content/drive/MyDrive/data/classes/02',
 '/content/drive/MyDrive/data/classes/04']
```

How can I transform the previous way into this:

```
['00',
 '01',
 '02',
 '03',
 ...,
 '44',
 '45',
 '100']
```

Comment: do not name `ListOfClasses` but `list_of_classes` instead, as strongly advised by Python's coding standards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using the `glob` module, I would use the `pathlib` module. `pathlib.Path.glob` yields a collection of `pathlib.Path` objects, rather than strings. Since they are path-objects, you can select only each path's `stem` to cull all the stuff that comes before. Then, you can sort the stem-strings as if they were integers:

```
from pathlib import Path

path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/data/classes/"

list_of_classes = sorted([p.stem for p in Path(path).glob("*")], key=int)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can split the strings on `/`. `rsplit('/', 1)` will split on the first `/` from the right, `rsplit('/', 1)[1]` will give you the folder name:

```
ListOfClasses = ['/content/drive/MyDrive/data/classes/42','/content/drive/MyDrive/data/classes/43','/content/drive/MyDrive/data/classes/36','/content/drive/MyDrive/data/classes/45']
[i.rsplit('/', 1)[1] for i in ListOfClasses]
```

Result:

```
['42', '43', '36', '45']
```

Answer (score 1):

You do **not** need glob or pathlib.

```
import os

list_of_classes = os.listdir('/content/drive/MyDrive/data/classes')
```